# Detect keycode ALT+L via Javascript

Tags: javascript, keycode

I try to detect if a user presses F12 or ALT + L.

```
document.onkeydown = function (event) {
    event = (event || window.event);
    if (event.keyCode == 123 || (event.keyCode == 18 && event.keyCode == 76)) {
        //do anything
        return false;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way is to create a bool to detect if the 'alt' key is currently held down and then a separate if to detect if that is true and if the L key as just been pressed - see the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/L4cb9/1

```
var held = false;

...

else if (event.keyCode == 18) {held = true;}

if (held == true && event.keyCode == 76) {
    alert();
}

...

document.onkeyup = function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 18) {held = false;}
}
```

This is applicable to holding any combination of keys - you can create an array for multiple key holds greater than two:

```
held = [];
...
if (event.keyCode == i) {held[i] = true;}
...
```

and so on

Comment: Isn't this too complicated? You can just check if `event.altKey` is true. Your suggestion could be useful if you want to detect if more keys (that are not alt/ctrl/shift)

Comment: Yes, considering the question at hand, gone a little over the top - managed to ignore was just alt - +1 yours as cleaner

Answer (score 2):

`event.keyCode` contains only one value. You can use `event.altKey` do detect if the `alt` key is pressed.

```
document.onkeydown = function (event) {
    event = (event || window.event);
    if (event.keyCode == 123 || (event.keyCode === 76 && event.altKey)) {
        //do something
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to use that, but the function is fireing just by pressing ALT